# Which Flask packages are redundant installations of Flask?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I have a Flask application that I have been trying to upload to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but for each version that i have uploaded I have been receiving status code 500.

I have been doing much research and found out that Elastic Beanstalk does not like python packages to be "double installed". I examined my `requirements.txt` file and did indeed find redundant package installs. I have, however, come across five packages that I am not sure about. I, of course, have Flask installed, but do I have to do anything special for the other five `Flask-otherPackage` packages that I have? Or are these different from the "double installs" that I wish to avoid?

```
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0
Flask-Uploads==0.2.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
```

**---- EDIT ----**

Here is my basic file structure:

```
ProjectRoot/
|    .ebextenstions/
|    |    python.config
|    .elasticbeanstalk/
|    |    config.yml
|    env
|    app/
|    |    static
|    |    templates
|    |    __init__.py
|    |    routes.py
|    .ebignore
|    application.py
|    requirements.txt
```

And, if 'package redundancy' is not the issue, I assume that I would have a misconfiguration in either `application.py` in `__init__.py` or in `python.config`.

**application.py**

```py
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080', use_reloader=True, debug=True)
```

**__init__.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES, patch_request_class
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
app.jinja_env.globals.update(zip=zip)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Xp-WmCb2dhQI_vNal9ScmA'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
# TODO: send the photos to S3 Bucket
app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = os.getcwd() + \
    '/app/static/gallery/'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

from app import routes
```

N.B.: the final line in `__init__.py` is an `import` because `routes` requires `from app import app, db, bcrypt`. I know that the Python formatters do not like this but this is the only way that seemed to work.

**python.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: application.py
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    /static/: app/static/
```

**`$ eb logs`**

```
============= i-060834a0883f81861 ==============
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------

[Tue Dec 31 00:17:56.219157 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24919] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:57.322771 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 12995] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:57.338693 2019] [so:warn] [pid 12995] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:57.340722 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 12995] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:57.340732 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 12995] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:57.341306 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 12995] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:57.341376 2019] [:warn] [pid 12995] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:57.341384 2019] [:warn] [pid 12995] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:57.343685 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12995] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:57.343703 2019] [core:notice] [pid 12995] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Dec 31 00:18:00.515594 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:18:01.518165 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 127.0.0.1:220] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:18:02.521050 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 127.0.0.1:220] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:18:03.523464 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 127.0.0.1:27616] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:22.067385 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:22.212131 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:22.356377 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:22.498942 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:22.640804 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:220] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:22.785146 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:27616] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:22.927952 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:23.070734 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:23.214636 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:23.357870 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:23.568607 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:220] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:23.781229 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:27616] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:23.993970 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:24.208521 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:21:24.424686 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 44.224.22.196:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:49:30.748801 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 166.137.12.62:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 00:49:33.843098 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 166.137.12.62:220] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 02:47:19.401713 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 92.118.160.29:27616] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 04:07:36.098763 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 193.57.40.46:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 04:32:27.321747 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 209.17.96.2:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 04:33:12.590378 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 104.219.234.53:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 05:14:54.901305 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 167.99.40.21:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 05:14:58.196551 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 167.99.40.21:220] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 05:15:01.340896 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 167.99.40.21:27616] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 08:52:55.003391 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 60.191.52.254:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 10:00:49.129535 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 5.101.0.209:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 10:34:12.108749 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 193.57.40.46:27616] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
 not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 10:00:49.129535 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 5.101.0.209:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does n
ot contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 10:34:12.108749 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 193.57.40.46:27616] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' doe
s not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 11:13:26.888344 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 170.238.36.21:220] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 11:17:58.647521 2019] [:error] [pid 13000] [remote 194.180.224.249:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13000): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:41.417269 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12995] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.579176 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 2887] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.596078 2019] [so:warn] [pid 2887] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.598442 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 2887] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.596078 2019] [so:warn] [pid 2887] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.598442 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 2887] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed
 in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.598452 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 2887] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.599068 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2887] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.599134 2019] [:warn] [pid 2887] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.599139 2019] [:warn] [pid 2887] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.601538 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2887] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:42.601557 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2887] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:45.741761 2019] [:error] [pid 2892] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=2892): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:46.744269 2019] [:error] [pid 2892] [remote 127.0.0.1:84] mod_wsgi (pid=2892): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:47.746954 2019] [:error] [pid 2892] [remote 127.0.0.1:84] mod_wsgi (pid=2892): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 12:01:48.749372 2019] [:error] [pid 2892] [remote 127.0.0.1:88] mod_wsgi (pid=2892): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 12:07:20.459842 2019] [:error] [pid 2892] [remote 166.170.0.35:88] mod_wsgi (pid=2892): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
[Tue Dec 31 12:07:20.723670 2019] [:error] [pid 2892] [remote 166.170.0.35:27480] mod_wsgi (pid=2892): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
```

If this is too far off the original topic, I will be happy to ask a new question. I am beginning to think that my issue is a misconfiguration. But why would t work well on localhost but it fails on the server? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I guess your research had brought you into the wrong direction. You should focus on the actual error. Show us your code and the error traceback.

Comment: Thank you @KlausD. for you suggestion. I have added some code and the latest logs.

Comment: Your `mod_wsgi` setup is incorrect. You should set the WSGI application from `application:application` to `application:app` or similar. Might be different in EB.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That is the answer! It is the same for EB. I had to change `app = Flask(__name__)` to `application = Flask(__name__)` (an alter everything associated).

Answer (score 0):

If u have follow the their documentation then probably u have install flask and some other related packages before running Ur  requirements.txt file.Then there will be conflict.So the best thing to do is create a fresh python virtual environment and run

```
pip freeze
```

see if there are any unwanted packages install in the environment and remove them all.After that run requirements.txt file to install all required packages.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

if this not work then it probably a error in ur code